How to implement MapLibre in Android and create/get tiles and customize styles for maps?
I'm new to using MapLibre in Android and I'm looking for guidance on how to implement it effectively. Specifically, I need help with creating and getting tiles, as well as customizing map styles. Can someone provide a comprehensive guide or point me to relevant resources to achieve these tasks with MapLibre in an Android application? Any sample code or tutorials would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Sure! I feel like you've got at least 3 different questions wrapped up in one here.

Creating tiles
Getting tiles into your app
Customizing map styles

Creating tiles is a pretty complex topic and for a full disclaimer, is part of what my company (Stadia Maps) does ;) If you really do want to create your own tiles, check out Planetiler or TileMaker.
Based on your question phrasing, I assume you're referring to vector tiles, as you can re-style these client-side. Loading tiles from a stylesheet is easy. Just add MapLibre to your Android app and point the map at the appropriate URL. Here's a tutorial.
As for style customization (again assuming vector), you have a few options. You can modify the style directly within MapLibre Native from your Java / Kotlin code. The basic pattern is wait till the style loads, and then manipulate it. I can't really offer a walkthrough on this but here are the API docs. If you want to customize a JSON stylesheet, you can do this using Maputnik, then save the style (ex: to your web host or embed in your app). You'll need vector tiles from either your own server or a host. Here's some further documentation on how to do this with Stadia Maps. It also touches on some deeper bits like custom fonts and sprites (icons).
